# JSon returning a string of HTML table to be displayed in the fnopen of jQuery datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, json

I have been trying to find an answer to this problem for over a month now with no luck so far.
So I started this work around.

I have a jQuery datatable which displays a case load of a resolver.

1. Id of claim
2. name of claimant
3. status of claim
4. last modification date
5. **total outstanding events**
6. last diary note
7. claim details pop up img

My problem is that on run time I generate 2 set of buttons one to display the details of the outstanding events and second to display the claimant details pop up.

everything was hunky dory until I had to get the outstanding event details from the server side and animate the table with html and further jQuery.

I read a lot and the closest I got was MVC which doesn't solve the problem.

So I started making a string with the html tags and inline jquery to pass back from the JSON service. It was working fine and the animation also works.

The problem now is when I deployed it to the server. It stops working. The HTML tags are there and the headers are being displayed but no actual data. I have checked the SQL query and it is returning the data. I have checked the inline string in debug mode and it also looks fine.

I can't figure out why it doesn't work on the server and if there is any other "better" way to do this.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

**code (Datatable)**

```
<div class="EventDetailsTable">
<asp:Repeater ID="TestRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="tblOverDueCases" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Claim Ref
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Claimant
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Last Action
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Status
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Events
                    </th>                        
                    <th>
                        Notes
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Claim Ref") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Claimant") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("[Last Action]")%>
                <%# Eval(" [Last Action Time]")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("[Status]")%>
            </td>
            <td class="center"> <%--JCTEST AddedControl center class--%>
                <%# Eval("[NoE]")%>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("[Latest Diary Note]").ToString()) ? "n/a" : "<img id='imgDiaryNote' src='Images/DiaryIcon.png' alt='noDiaryNote' />")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody> </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

**code (jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {


var nCloneTh = document.createElement('th');
var nCloneTd = document.createElement('td');
nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<img id="btnEventDet" src="Images/details_open.png" />';
nCloneTd.className = "center";

var nCloneTh2 = document.createElement('th');
var nCloneTd2 = document.createElement('td');
nCloneTd2.innerHTML = '<img id="btnClaimInfo" src="Images/InfoIcon.png" />';
nCloneTd2.className = "center";

$('#tblOverDueCases thead tr').each(function () {
    this.insertBefore(nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0]);
    this.insertBefore(nCloneTh2, this.childNodes[14]);
});
/*hack to display the info column as the last col*/
$('#tblOverDueCases tbody tr').each(function () {
    this.insertBefore(nCloneTd.cloneNode(true), this.childNodes[0]);
    this.insertBefore(nCloneTd2.cloneNode(true), this.childNodes[14]);

});

var oTable = $('#tblOverDueCases').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [10, 25, 50,-1],
        [10, 25, 50,"All"]
    ]
});


$('#btnEventDet').live('click', function () {
    var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (this.src.match('details_close')) {
        /* This row is already open - close it */
        this.src = "Images/details_open.png";
        oTable.fnClose(nTr);
        /*change background color*/
        unfocusRow(nTr);
    }
    else if (this.src.match('details_open')) {
        /*collapse all open rows*/
        $('table img').each(function (event) {
            var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            if (this.src.match('details_close')) {
                /* This row is already open - close it */
                this.src = "Images/details_open.png";
                oTable.fnClose(nTr);
                /*Change the highlight back to the orginal colors*/
                unfocusRow(nTr);
            }
        });

        /* Open this row */
        this.src = "Images/details_close.png";
        oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details');
        /*Highlight and bold the selected row*/
        focusRow(nTr);
    }
});
/*test diary note button*/
var highlightRow;
$('#imgDiaryNote').live('click', function () {
    var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    highlightRow = nTr;        
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
    var sOut = aData[1];


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DiaryView.aspx/GetDiaryNote",
        data: "{'leadID': " + sOut + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg){
            $('#lbDiaryNote').text(msg.d);
             //centering with css
            centerPopup("#DNWindow", '#backGroundDiaryNote');
            //load popup
            loadPopup("#DNWindow", '#backGroundDiaryNote');

            //highlight row
            focusRow(highlightRow);
        }
        });

    });

function fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr) {
var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
var sOut = aData[1];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DiaryView.aspx/GetData",
    data: "{'leadID': " + sOut + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        oTable.fnOpen(nTr, msg.d, 'details');
    }
});

return "";
}
```

**code(JSON)**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string GetData(int leadID)
{
    #region string table code

    OverDueEvents overDueEvent = new OverDueEvents();
    DataSet ds = Query_OverdueEvents.Instance.OverdueEvents(followUpTime, userID, leadTypeID, leadID);
    DataSet innerDs = new DataSet();

    int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();

    returnString.AppendLine(GenerateJQueryAndHTML.Instance.GenEventDetailsSubTablejQuery());
    returnString.AppendLine(GenerateJQueryAndHTML.Instance.GenEventSubTableHeaders());

    List<OverDueEvents> listOverDueClaims = new List<OverDueEvents>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        overDueEvent = new OverDueEvents();
        overDueEvent.OverDueClaim.LeadID = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0];
        overDueEvent.LeadEventID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        overDueEvent.OverDueEvent.EventID = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2];
        overDueEvent.OverDueEvent.FollowUpTime = overDueEvent.OverDueEvent.GetFollowUpTime(overDueEvent.OverDueEvent.EventID);
        overDueEvent.OverDueEvent.EventName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();
        overDueEvent.EventActioned = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString();
        overDueEvent.EventDueDate = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString();
        overDueEvent.DaysOverDue = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[6];

        innerDs = Query_NextPossibleEvents.Instance.GetNextPossibleEvents(followUpTime, userID, leadTypeID, leadID, overDueEvent.OverDueEvent.EventID);

        for (int nextEventCount = 0; nextEventCount < innerDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count; nextEventCount++)
        {
            Events nextAction = new Events();
            nextAction.EventName = innerDs.Tables[0].Rows[nextEventCount].ItemArray[1].ToString();

            overDueEvent.NextActions.Add(nextAction);
        }
        listOverDueClaims.Add(overDueEvent);
    }
    int panelID = 1;
    foreach (var events in listOverDueClaims)
    {
        returnString.AppendLine(GenerateJQueryAndHTML.Instance.GenEventSubTableCol(panelID, events.OverDueEvent.EventName));
        panelID++;
    }

    returnString.AppendLine(GenerateJQueryAndHTML.Instance.GenOutTableClosingTags());

    int panelCount = 1;
    foreach (var overDueEvents in listOverDueClaims)
    {
        returnString.AppendLine(GenerateJQueryAndHTML.Instance.GenNextEventTable(panelCount, overDueEvents));
        panelCount++;
    }

    returnString.AppendLine(GenerateJQueryAndHTML.Instance.GenEventSubTableClosingTags());

    return returnString.ToString();

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: A little code would help a lot.

Comment: let me know if you would like to see the custom html gen functions too... Again thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your jquery code. The first is that the 'data' parameter expects an actual js object, not a stringified object. The second, and I may be wrong here, is that your are apparently using your web method with an asPx file. To my knowledge, these should be used with asMx files.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DiaryView.aspx/GetData",    //Not sure if an ASPX can have a web method. I always use an ASMX for these.
    //data: "{'leadID': " + sOut + "}", //data is an actual object, not a stringified json object use:this instead.
    data: {
        'leadID': sOut
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        oTable.fnOpen(nTr, msg.d, 'details');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The aspx service works fine. The problem was with static web methods. It kept on changing every time a new user logged in. As these services were live and called upon when plus image was clicked they were failing as the updated user id didn't have the case assigned to it.